# Android "no app can perform this action" through URL but works fine on phone

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, m4v

I'm having a frustrating day.

The video links on this test page I'm doing for a friend of mine work in Desktop Firefox/Chrome and iOS, but not IE 11 or (more importantly) Android:

http://davelozinski.com/testvideos

**Issue #1 and most important:**

In the default Samsung Android "Internet" browser, it comes up with "*No app can perform this action*".

However!

If I load the video directly onto the phone (in this case, a Galaxy S4 mini), the video plays perfectly when I tap it.

This is affecting videos we'll have to be producing as we need them to play using the default Android browser.

I have found no way to associate the browser to the inbuilt "gallery" application to play the video.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

**Issue #2:**

In IE11, a popup dialog comes up asking if we want to "open or save" the video file. Either way, it downloads it directly and then we have to double-click to open instead of being able to view it in the browser itself. 
How do we get around this so it'll play directly in the browser too?

Thank you!

Comment: **1)** Try renaming file to end with **.mp4** & see if it works. **2)** Try exporting your video codec (h264) within MP4 container instead of M4V container. Inside they look similar (if not exact same) but you never know what code the "playing" side wrote...

Comment: Neither one of these ideas works. My phone keeps coming up and saying, "no app can perform this action" even though the links work on other people's Android phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

Under "Application Manager | All" there was an item called "Downloads" with a bright green down pointing arrow as an icon.

This was turned off.

When I turned this one and clicked on a video link, my phone started prompting me now whether I wanted to download the video, or use a thing called "Android System" to handle it.

Choosing the latter my phone now plays videos.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Try this...

If not possible open it in android **webview**.

Comment: Where is WebView? I'm running Android 4.4.2 and see it nowhere. I have to go to the standard browser to type in the URL. When I do that, there's no options that I can see either.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not interested in "developing"; just doing front-end web design. I thought on Android 4.4.2 WebView should be activated by default and just work with the default internet browser. I was looking for something like, "go to application manager and make sure xxx is turned on."

Comment: I am still confused.What do you want to do with the video URL from your android application?

Comment: there is no Android application per se. It's a web page. See my question. We're creating web pages with videos, and the videos are not playing in the standard Android browser when one clicks on the link. However, if the videos are loaded directly onto the phone(s) they play fine. Users aren't going to want to have to download videos to later watch -- they want to tap on a page, and have them play.